# how to check hibernate session connection is in read-only mode in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

how to check hibernate session contains connection is in read-only mode.

Currently checking it using

```
Session.connection().isReadOnly()
```

but connection is deprecated marked, Is there any other way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use isDefaultReadOnly() method on session object. This tells you, (From Hibernate Javadoc)

> Will entities and proxies that are loaded into this session be made read-only by default?

Also, you can use isReadOnly(object) method as well. This will tell you (Again From hibernate javadoc)

> Is the specified entity or proxy read-only?

I hope combination of these two will server your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
private boolean isReadOnly;

public boolean isReadOnly() {
  this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().doWork(new Work() {

    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
      isReadOnly = connection.isReadOnly();
    }
  });
  return isReadOnly;
}
```